# How to avoid downloading mp4 videos on website?

Tags: video-streaming, hosting, mp4

I am creating an LMS (online courses) solution, the content is mostly in MP4 format and we are going to use an html viewer to display the content on the page, another option is to host the content on VIMEO.com, is there a way to avoid the user download the videos with extension browser or tool to extract this content ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Not if you want people to play the video. From the server perspective there is no difference between download and playing. The server doesn't know if the client is displaying the video on the screen, or saving it to the disk.